# Migration of Web/Application Server

Tags: 2013, migration

We're in the process of upgrading our servers from `2008R2` to `2012R2` and I am currently looking at migrating our SharePoint web/application server (we only have a small deployment so are both on the same box) to 2012.  I'm not touching the SharePoint SQL database at all.

I've setup the new `2012R2` server and installed SharePoint Server 2013 onto it, can I simply add this new machine to the SharePoint farm and have the old and the new running side by side for a few days, then remove the old server from the farm?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue if you remove the old server in couple of days.I did the same for 2010 farm.Here are steps I followed.

- Install SharePoint on New server( SharePoint version should be same as existing server
- add the service account into server i.e farm admin in local admin group...you can copy from existing server.
- Join the new server to farm.
- make sure you select this server will host central admin.(as you have all on one server).
- now turn on the services which you have on existing server to new server( i.e upa, search service( modify the topology).
- update the DNS record to point new server.
- Update the AAM setting, if using the server name and port number.
- change IIS bindings(if any).
- make the web.config modification if any.

Once everything work as expected then you can remove the old server from farm.